# Beacon advertising Interval in 100 ms and few detections

Tags: arduino, ibeacon

I have configured a beacon with a broadcast interval or advertising interval of 100 ms and I'm using some boards, redBear DUO right now, to scan this and other beacons.

In the RedBear scanning program I have set an scan window of 60 ms and Scan interval of 60 ms.

Shouldn't I receive like 10 signals of this beacons per second? In my understanding at least, this should be the behaviour, but the reality is that I usually see 1 or two detections per second (sometimes more) and sometimes I don't see it for 3-5 seconds, which seems really strange for me.

Someone can explain if I'm misunderstanding some concepts?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the timing is too tight - the board needs some time to detect/ receive/ decode the beacon message. Add some gaps, overlaps, and non-responsive times, and voila, you may only get a few signals out of 10. If something disturbes reception (mixer, microwave, vaccuum) you may see longer gaps. I'd say "happens all the time".

I have some general Arduino/ BT/ WiFi experience, but somebody with a redBear DUO may have some additional information.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I have tried with several scan and interval windows, ranging from 10ms to 4 seconds and the behaviour is similar. I have seen in the RedBear forum a post with a similar problem that's still beign resolved. http://discuss.redbear.cc/t/need-faster-scans-in-ble-central-mode-blescanner-sketch/871/25